# Python "cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not a query" for Oracle Function return type cursor

Tags: python

Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong because with same value if I execute procedure which gives multiple lines of response but in python which is failing and giving exception in cursor call to function.

```
    -----Oracle Function----------
    FUNCTION get_details (id IN VARCHAR2, actNo IN VARCHAR2, code IN VARCHAR2)
            RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR

    ----Oracle Function Logic----------

     OPEN cur_msg_dtls FOR SELECT NAME,VALUE,CODE FROM TABLE

     returns cur_msg_dtls

    ----Python Code--------
    import cx_Oracle

if __name__ == '__main__':

    con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/pass@host.com:1521/schema')

    cur_var = con.cursor()

    actNo = 'actNo';
    code ='Code';
    Id ='Id';

    try:
        cur_var.callfunc('SCHEMA.PKG.GET_DETAILS',cx_Oracle.CURSOR, (Id,actNo, actCd))
        print ("hello")
        print(cur_var)
        print(type(cur_var))
        for row in cur_var:
            print(row)
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
      print (e)
    finally:
        cur_var.close()
        con.close()
    pass
    ----Error--------------
    hello
<cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to username/pass@host.com:1521/schema>>
<class 'cx_Oracle.Cursor'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TestDBPRoc.py", line 26, in <module>
    for row in cur_var:
cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not a query
```

Comment: Please include the full trace back

Comment: The [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.callfunc) says the second parameter should be the return type. I don't know anything more than that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am from java background I don't know why sometimes python is not giving enough trace for exception or error.I updated the full trace what I see in eclipse IDE

Comment: @sunleo shouldn't you use the return value from `callfunc`?

Comment: Look at samples like https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/PLSQLFunction.py